# How do I server a specific directory with possible sub directories in Django 1.7?

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

[image]

I've got this Django web app that allows users to upload various video files.  The directories are all under media, and any subdirectories are created to uniquely idenfitfy the file.  I already am serving static files, but all I want to do is serve the entire 'media' directory.  Is there any simple way that I can server this?

```
"""
Django settings for elearn project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    BASE_DIR + '/templates/',
)

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
#DEBUG = False

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'lessons',
    'registration'
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app.wsgi.application'

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/elearn/static',
)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I purposely left out sensitive credentials.

Also this is how I'm serving the static files currently

```
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with it.  For something simple like dating the file, you can set `upload_to` to `%Y/%m/%d`. You can also write a function to return a relative URL as a string, like such:

```
def widget_file_name(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['widget', instance.user.username, filename])

class Widget(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=widget_file_name)
```

**UPDATE**

If you're just looking for a way to serve that media directory, you could always just specify it as your MEDIA_ROOT in settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/path/to/media'
```

Now, keep in mind, in production, you should let your web server (nginx, apache, etc) serve static and media files, so you'll need to set that up in whatever you use as a proxy pass web server.  To serve the files in this directory, you will also need to set a MEDIA_URL. `MEDIA_URL = 'media'` will usually suffice

Comment: I'm going to store it on the file system because it would put to much strain on the database

Comment: That's fine, the 'upload_to' is a relative path, to your MEDIA_ROOT.  Django doesn't store files in the database by default.  It stores the path in the database, rather than the file itself.

Comment: The issues isn't creating the files or subdirectories, it's serving the actual file.  I'm embedding it in an iframe and the source will be something like 'domain.com/media/4/11/sample.mp4'